# CMake errors (windows gui)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, irrlicht

I have been trying long time to fix this problem with no success .

I want to configure and generate a source ;
When I try to do that , I receive a couple of errors.

This is the results :

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1106 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.54.0

Boost include path: C:/Program Files (x86)/boost_1_54_0

The following Boost libraries could not be found:

      boost_serialization

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR = IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
IRRLICHT_LIBRARY = IRRLICHT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
Could NOT find IRRLICHT (missing:  IRRLICHT_LIBRARY IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:16 (link_directories):
This command specifies the relative path

IRRLICHT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND

as a link directory.

Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:16 (link_directories):
  This command specifies the relative path

as a link directory.

Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run cmake-gui program and set proper paths (sources and build).

Then you will be able to edit manualy some variables in window below.

You need to find there:

```
Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY
```

and

```
Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_DEBUG
```

and set them so they will point to proper boost libraries ex:

```
D:/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_serialization-mgw48-mt-1_53.a
D:/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/libboost_serialization-mgw48-mt-d-1_53.a
```

-d- in name of second path stands for debug

Comment: Great :)
One problem Solved.

Still IRRLICHT problem

tried to add entry to the include dir but still problem

Comment: Great :) One problem Solved. Still IRRLICHT problem tried to add entry to the include dir but still problem

Comment: @user2824393: for irrlicht it should be similar: set value of IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR so it points to directory where includes are. It usually looks like: d:/libs/irrlicht/include. And then same for library, but here you need to point to lib file directly

Comment: Hey ;
I try to set the values as you described without success !
still the same !
and when I configure ; these two values deleted automatically

Another idea ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: @user2824393: please tell me how do you try to find irrlicht in your CmakeList.txt. Irrlicht is not a library directly handled by find_package so I guess You did some tricks. I'll need to know them to help You.

Comment: Note : The CMakeLists.txt file was ready when I download this project.

The code in the file written like this :

find_package(Irrlicht REQUIRED)
...
another things without Irrlicht
...
include_directories("${IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR}" "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include")
link_directories("${IRRLICHT_LIBRARY}" "${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

Comment: @user2824393: I see. I guess then that this project provides it's own subscript for finding irrlicht. You can find proper file. It should be called irrlichtConfig.cmake or irrlicht-config.cmake. Find this file and share it. I'll need it to do tests on my machine

Comment: Here is the file : https://code.google.com/p/ratslam/source/browse/trunk/cmake/FindIrrlicht.cmake

Comment: setup environmental variable IRRDIR to main directory of library like: d:/libs/irrlicht-1.8. Then try again

Comment: Hey ; 
I tried to set them on the cmake gui  and on the computer -> properties -> ... -> variables ; without success.

in the website they said : "We are aware that the build system needs some more work, so if finding dependencies is not working properly, a workaround is to edit the CMakeLists.txt file, remove the FindPackage lines that are not working and manually set the include and lib directories by adding: include_directories(dir1 dir2 ...)
link_directories(dir1 dir2 ...) "


Can you please explain how exactly to set them : The syntax especially.

Comment: Can explain what worked with you ?
Or how to write the syntax in the CMakeLists as they describe ?

Comment: I've opened cmd and set variable this way: set IRRDIR=d:/libs/irrlicht-1.8, then I ran cmake-gui (in cmd) and I've manualy set ITTLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR to D:/libs/irrlicht-1.8/include and IRRLICHT_LIBRARY to D:/libs/irrlicht-1.8/lib/Win32-gcc/libIrrlicht.a. If You want to do as they suggest as a last resort, edit include_directories("${IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR}" "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include") and instead of ${IRRLICHT_INCLUDE_DIR} enter your path. then do The same for link_directories("${IRRLICHT_LIBRARY}" "${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}") where ${IRRLICHT_LIBRARY} will be lib file

Comment: Thank you very much.
I delete the "find package" statement for irrlicht and and set manually the include&link directions and it's works :).
but in the link-directions line , also there is "${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}" that makes error ! what I can set there as a path ?? note : when I remove it it's pass the configure successfully so it's the last error I have :)

Comment: I think its works now ! I set it ti the "libs" directory!

Thank you Very much